# How to open browser session for Selenium node running in Kubernetes

Tags: selenium, kubernetes, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium node running in Kubernetes, and I'm able to port-forward the hub (for development and debugging purposes) and access it locally, with nodes being registered. However, due to what I'm using it for, I hit a CAPTCHA which requires opening the browser and solving it myself. The session data is then saved, and the CAPTCHA is never needed again. I can't for the life of me figure out how to access that browser instance running on the node. I have tried port-forwarding the node to no avail, and I can't find any documentation detailing how to physically view the session that is running on a node.

I'm happy to answer any clarifying questions that may be needed. For reference, here are some screenshots:

Hub console:
[image: Hub console port-forwarded]

Node port-forwarded:
[image: Node port-forwarded]

EDIT -- In response to a request for more details

The hub YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    name: selenium-hub
spec:
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4444
      targetPort: 4444
    - name: node
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5555
      targetPort: 5555

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub-deployment
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
    name: selenium-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-hub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-hub
          image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-xenon
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xmx1024m"
            - name: POOL_MAX
              value: "500"
            - name: GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT
              value: "-1"
            - name: GRID_JETTY_MAX_THREADS
              value: "-1"
            - name: GRID_NODE_POLLING
              value: "5000"
            - name: GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE
              value: "5000"
            - name: GRID_TIMEOUT
              value: "600"
            - name: GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT
              value: "600"
            - name: GRID_MAX_SESSION
              value: "5"
            - name: GRID_UNREGISTER_IF_STILL_DOWN_AFTER
              value: "30000"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4444
              protocol: TCP
```

The node YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome
  labels:
    name: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  selector:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
    browser: chrome
  ports:
    - name: nodeport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5555
      targetPort: 5555
    - name: node-port-grid
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4444
      targetPort: 4444
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome-deployment
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
    name: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-node-chrome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-node-chrome
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-node-chrome
          image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-xenon
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xmx512m -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING"
            - name: SE_OPTS
              value: ""
            - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR
              value: "selenium-hub"
            - name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT
              value: "4444"
            - name: REMOTE_HOST
              value: ""
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4444
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 5555
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dshm
              mountPath: /dev/shm
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir: { "medium": "Memory" }
```

Comment: Please provide more details on: what type of cluster, how it's deployed, how selenium is deployed (ideally share deployment and service). From the first glance it can be service with `nodePort` or `ingress`

Comment: @moonkotte i added all deployment yamls, and it is deployed on EKS

Comment: Thank you! So I deployed everything to GKE (same, but different) and created services as `loadbalancer` and I can access hub, but not node. Could you please also briefly describe what exactly you forwarded? And where should I connect to? Because port-forwarding works with pods, not services.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I used the official helm chart to great success, using VNC to access the running test. I followed this: https://github.com/sayems/selenium.grid

Comment: @jclasley Based on [documentation about selenium grid in kubernetes project](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium) looks like port-forward is the right option to use. However [they suggest exposing selenium-hub](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium#using-google-container-engine) as loadbalancer (for EKS should work the same)